# Handling initial value in collectAsState in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-flow

I'm working on a Jetpack Compose project where I have a composable function that collects a Flow using `collectAsState`. I'm facing an issue with handling the `initial` value in a more idiomatic way. Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            FlowExampleTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                ) {
                    NavigationScreen()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun NavigationScreen(viewModel: MainViewModel = koinViewModel()) {

    val destination by viewModel.currentDestination.collectAsState(initial = ScreenName.ScreenOne)

    LaunchedEffect(viewModel, destination) {
        viewModel.navigateToDeviceSelection(false)
    }

    LaunchedEffect(key1 = destination) {
        Log.e(">> destination", destination.route)
    }

    Column {
        Text(text = destination.route, fontSize = 20.sp)

    }
}
```

**MainViewModel.kt**

```
class MainViewModel(
    private val navigationHandler: NavigationHandler
) : ViewModel() {
    val currentDestination: Flow<NavigationDestination> =
        navigationHandler.destination.shareIn(
            viewModelScope,
            SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(),
        )

    fun navigateToDeviceSelection(isValid: Boolean) {
        val destination = if (isValid) {
            ScreenName.ScreenOne
        } else {
            ScreenName.ScreenTwo
        }
        println(">> destination ${destination.route}")
        navigationHandler.navigate(destination)
    }
}
```

**NavigationDestination**

```
interface NavigationDestination {
    val route: String
}
```

**NavigationHandler.kt**

```
interface NavigationHandler {
    val destination: SharedFlow<ScreenName>
    fun navigate(navigationDestination: ScreenName)
}
```

**Navigator.kt**

```
class Navigator : NavigationHandler {

    private val _destination: MutableSharedFlow<ScreenName> = MutableSharedFlow(
        replay = 1,
        onBufferOverflow = BufferOverflow.DROP_OLDEST
    )

    override val destination: SharedFlow<ScreenName> = _destination.asSharedFlow()

    override fun navigate(navigationDestination: ScreenName) {
        _destination.tryEmit(navigationDestination)
    }
}
```

**ScreenName**

```
sealed class ScreenName(override val route: String) : NavigationDestination {

    object ScreenOne : ScreenName("ScreenOne") {
        object ChildOne : ScreenName("ChildOne")
    }

    object ScreenTwo : ScreenName("ScreenTwo")
}
```

When I run the code it always print first `ScreenOne` then move to other condition like `ScreenTwo` according to condition used inside `navigateToDeviceSelection` function called. I just give me `initial` by default because `collectAsState` need that. I am using `SharedFlow` because I want to trigger same event repeatedly. Above code is just example of 2 events but actually is more than that.

My main expected output will be to print first according to `navigateToDeviceSelection` logic not by default value which I provided by `collectAsState`. I don't want to use `null` because this example is very basic and I need to add more events in here.

Comment: You have "ScreenOne" as the default value, so this is the expected behavior. What are you trying to implement? Can you add more details on the expected flow?

Comment: Hey @Abhimanyu thanks for relply. I already updated the description. Please have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `LaunchedEffect` that you use to navigate to the desired screen is called asynchronously. There is no guarantee when and even if that effect is executed (although most of the time it will be pretty fast), but in the meantime the current thread continues and needs a destination for the `Text` composable to display. That is why you need the initial value.

If you would use a `StateFlow` you could move the entire handling of the navigation (including the initial value that is then set by `stateIn` instead of `collectAsState`) to the view model. Perhaps that would allow you to restructure your navigation logic so it always provides the desired start screen as the initial value of the flow.

I am not sure why you don't want to use a `StateFlow` anyways. Yes, it will drop repeated values. But then again, the collected value `destination` in `NavigationScreen` is (a delegate to) a Compose State object, so repeatedly changing it to the same value won't trigger a recomposition anyways. If you do not do any fancy stuff with that flow at another location outside of a composable I fail to see the difference.

If you want to keep the navigation logic as it is you can always provide an initial value of `null` to the flow to indicate that there is no real value yet. That way you could just skip displaying any screen at all (or display a loading indicator) until a value is supplied.

By the way, you should change your collection method to `collectAsStateWithLifecycle` to automatically subscribe and unsubscribe the flow according to the current state of the composable. You need the artifact `androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-compose` for that. Also you need to change the type of `currentDestination` to `SharedFlow` (or `StateFlow`, for that matter).

Comment: Hey @Leviathan thanks for explaining me in detail. Can you please give me example with stateflow and  trigger same event twice?

Comment: Just use `val currentDestination: StateFlow<NavigationDestination> = navigationHandler.destination.stateIn(...)` in the view model. I don't know what you mean by "trigger same event twice".

Comment: I mean if i want to trigger same event twice than how can I do that? If same event then `LauncEffect` will not trigger, so how can I solve this problem.

Comment: Depends entirely on why you even want that. You can create a new question with detailed information about what you want to achieve by that. And please keep in mind that Compose is state-driven. If a variable doesn't change its value, nothing changes in the UI - by design. You would need to explain how what you want to achieve doesn't contradict that paradigm.

Comment: Hey @Leviathan i added another question based on problem. Can you please guide me on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/78130663/8266651). Thanks