# Issue with Composable Navigation and ViewModel Updates

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-flow, jetpack-compose-navigation

I have viewmodel on that base I want to navigate through screens. I am adding very basic example to explain my problem.

**MainActivity**

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            NavigationScreen()
        }
    }
}
```

**MainViewModel**

```
class MainViewModel(private val navigationHandler: NavigationHandler) : ViewModel() {

    val currentDestination: StateFlow<ScreenName?> =
        navigationHandler.destination.stateIn(
            viewModelScope,
            SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(),
            initialValue = null
        )

    fun navigateToDeviceSelection(isValid: Boolean) {
        val destination = if (isValid) {
            ScreenName.ScreenOne
        } else {
            ScreenName.ScreenTwo
        }
        println(">> destination ${destination.route}")
        navigationHandler.navigate(destination)
    }
}
```

I created a custom navigation class which handle the logic and navigate the screen accordingly using `StateFlow`.

**NavigationDestination**

```
interface NavigationDestination {
    val route: String
}
```

**NavigationHandler**

```
interface NavigationHandler {
    val destination: StateFlow<ScreenName?>
    fun navigate(navigationDestination: ScreenName)
}
```

**Navigator**

```
class Navigator : NavigationHandler {

    private val _destination: MutableStateFlow<ScreenName?> = MutableStateFlow(null)

    override val destination: StateFlow<ScreenName?> = _destination.asStateFlow()

    override fun navigate(navigationDestination: ScreenName) {
        _destination.value = navigationDestination
    }
}
```

**ScreenName**

```
sealed class ScreenName(override val route: String) : NavigationDestination {

    object ScreenOne : ScreenName("ScreenOne") {
        object ChildOne : ScreenName("ChildOne")
        object ChildTwo : ScreenName("ChildTwo")
    }

    object ScreenTwo : ScreenName("ScreenTwo")
}
```

Now when I consume this **MainViewModel** inside composable like below code

```
@Composable
fun NavigationScreen(
    viewModel: MainViewModel = koinViewModel(),
    navController: NavHostController = rememberNavController()
) {

    val destinationState by viewModel.currentDestination.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()

    LaunchedEffect(destinationState) {
        destinationState?.let {
            navController.navigate(it.route) {
                popUpTo(navController.graph.startDestinationId) {
                    inclusive = true
                }
                launchSingleTop = true
            }
        }
    }

    LaunchedEffect(viewModel) {
        viewModel.navigateToDeviceSelection(true)
    }

    NavHost(
        navController = navController,
        startDestination = ScreenName.ScreenOne.route,
        route = "parentRoute"
    ) {

        nestedGraphSample(navController, viewModel)

        composable(ScreenName.ScreenTwo.route) {
            Text(text = "Screen Two Route")
        }
    }
}

private fun NavGraphBuilder.nestedGraphSample(
    navController: NavHostController,
    viewModel: MainViewModel
) {
    navigation(
        startDestination = ScreenName.ScreenOne.ChildOne.route,
        route = ScreenName.ScreenOne.route
    ) {
        composable(ScreenName.ScreenOne.ChildOne.route) {

            LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
                delay(5.seconds)
                navController.navigate(ScreenName.ScreenOne.ChildTwo.route) {
                    popUpTo(navController.graph.startDestinationId) {
                        inclusive = true
                    }
                    launchSingleTop = true
                }
            }

            Text(text = "Screen Child One Route")
        }

        composable(ScreenName.ScreenOne.ChildTwo.route) {
            LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
                delay(5.seconds)
                viewModel.navigateToDeviceSelection(true)
            }
            Text(text = "Screen Child Two Route")
        }
    }
}
```

My primary issue arises when the user initially invokes `navigateToDeviceSelection`, leading to redirection to `ScreenName.ScreenOne` and the storage of this value within `destinationState`. Subsequently, when navigating via `navController`, the destination state remains unchanged, resulting in redirection to another screen. Additionally, upon invoking `navigateToDeviceSelection` within `ScreenName.ScreenOne.ChildTwo.route`, the destination state fails to update, rendering the `LaunchedEffect` ineffective, and causing the user to remain stuck in the `ScreenName.ScreenOne.ChildTwo.route` screen. To address this challenge, I seek a solution that avoids accessing `destinationState` within nested composable functions, as this example is basic, and I prefer not to pass this variable to nested children.

Comment: I feel like I’ve answered a similar question of yours about six months ago, but maybe it was someone else. You cannot use StateFlow or State to represent navigation destinations or other kinds of events in the traditional way, because events are not state. The Android documentation suggests using a mutable class as your state type. The mutable class has only one mutable property, and this property does not participate in `equals` so define it outside the data class constructor. The property is a `var isEventConsumed = false`. Only navigate if this is false and change it to true when you do

Comment: Hey @Tenfour04 thanks for response. I got your point. What do you mean mutable class and property? What do you mean define it outside the data constructor. Can you give me example please if you don't mind and I make sure to never do this mistake again.

Comment: It looks like they updated their guidance [at this page](https://developer.android.com/topic/architecture/ui-layer/events) and no longer suggest mutable classes, but rather a StateFlow where you use `stateFlow.update` to immediately update the value so it can't be consumed multiple times before it changes.

Comment: Yes they updated the document

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think to update your code to the [Android developer guidance](https://developer.android.com/topic/architecture/ui-layer/events), the shortest path is:

1. Add a function to report the navigation event has been handled to your NavigationHandler:

```
class Navigator : NavigationHandler {

    private val _destination: MutableStateFlow<ScreenName?> = MutableStateFlow(null)

    override val destination: StateFlow<ScreenName?> = _destination.asStateFlow()

    override fun navigate(navigationDestination: ScreenName) {
        _destination.value = navigationDestination
    }

    /** Must be called by collecting class when navigation event has been responded to. */
    override fun consumeNavigationEvent() {
        _destination.update { null } 
    }
}
```

2. It seems that currently your NavigationHandler layer is redundant complexity because it doesn't abstract away anything for the ViewModel. Any change made to the NavigationHandler also has to be made to the ViewModel to be able to handle it. It's also very weird that you are using `stateIn` on a StateFlow, creating a redundant StateFlow. I would just delete the entire NavigationHandler and Navigator, but if you don't, you need to at least remove the redundant StateFlow and need to pass through this new function.

```
class MainViewModel(private val navigationHandler: NavigationHandler) : ViewModel() {

    val currentDestination: StateFlow<ScreenName?> get() =
        navigationHandler.destination

    fun navigateToDeviceSelection(isValid: Boolean) {
        val destination = if (isValid) {
            ScreenName.ScreenOne
        } else {
            ScreenName.ScreenTwo
        }
        println(">> destination ${destination.route}")
        navigationHandler.navigate(destination)
    }

    /** Must be called by collecting class when navigation event has been responded to. */
    override fun consumeNavigationEvent() {
       navigationHandler.destination.consumeNavigationEvent()
    }
}
```

3. Where you are responding to events, you must consume the event when you use it.

```
    LaunchedEffect(destinationState) {
        destinationState?.let {
            viewModel.consumeNavigationEvent()
            navController.navigate(it.route) {
                popUpTo(navController.graph.startDestinationId) {
                    inclusive = true
                }
                launchSingleTop = true
            }
        }
    }
```

But like I said, I think you can simplify your code quite a bit by eliminating the NavigationHandler and Navigator.

You might also consider clarifying some of your function names. For example `NavigationHandler.navigate()` and `MainViewModel.navigateToDestination()` do not actually perform any navigation. They only set the desired new destination. It makes it confusing that your Composable has to tell the ViewModel to navigate and then it also has to tell the NavHost to navigate, but these are doing two different things.

Comment: I removed the `NavigationHandler` from my project and used `StateFlow` directly in viewmodel.

Comment: I have one doubt you used `viewModel.consumeNavigationEvent()` inside launcheffect of top `NavigationScreen` composable. Can I use inside `nestedGraphSample`composable inside launcheffect? I tried it not working to update the state. Is there any reason behind this?

Comment: I haven't actually worked with NavGraphBuilder myself yet. I don't know.